# Compiling and Linking against plplot library on debian

Tags: plot, codeblocks, linker-errors

I am using Code::Blocks IDE on Debian 8. I have installed the plplot library form synaptic (not from source). When I create new project in C::B and try to run a simple plplot example the compiler do not recognize the includes and the linker do not recognize the plplot library. So how to compile and link with plplot library when I have installed it from Synaptic not from source? Is this possible, or I should remove current packages and install from source only?

In general when I install new library (from synaptic or from source) how to find out what should be the compiler flags and search directories and for the linker too? I think installing from source should be the less problems prone way!

Till now I am doing file search for the included header and add its directory to the search path for the compiler. But this is very cumbersome and naive approach. It will be better if I add compiler flag that does all this job, but how to find it out. Some flags I find in forums but not in the documentation of the libraries. Why there is no file with the third program library to tell what flags should one use? Nevertheless when the o files are done I have linker errors like "undefined reference to...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the plplot library the linker flag should be `-lplplotd`. For the compiler options I have no flags but I did a search for the unknown headers and added their directories to the search directories path. Now the [Example 00](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/examples.php?demo=00) works fine. Though I found the `-lplplotd` flag by shooting! For the x11 examples one should add the flag `-lplplotcxxd`.

In general I got that to find the linker flag I have to search for the library `so` file and the name of the file commonly is the flag, e.g. for the library `libplplotcxxd.so` the flag is `-lplplotcxxd`.

Anyway, I'd be glad if someone tells me a better clue on finding these linker flags.